# How to interpret Java GC analysis using Java Mission Control

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

Attaching the image for the Full GC. What I am unclear is what else this tool Java Mission control will provide that will help me to understand where it has occurred and why? Like the functions that it was trying to execute at this time.

Any pointers from pundits who perform gc analysis.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Java Mission Control (JMC) is a set of tools helping to analyze what happens in the JVM. It's composed of 3 parts:

1. JMX console - monitors JVM activity in real-time and allows to
   change some of JVM's properties without restarting it. Moreover, it
   can be used as alerting system to send notifications when the
   threshold of some metrics is reached (e.g. CPU use is equal to 90%)
2. Java Flight Recorder (JFR) - JFR collects data over time. It can be used separately from JMC but the most often both are used together. Please note that the JFR can be freely used only for evaluation purposes. Used in production servers it requires a commercial licence.
3. external plugins - as in the case of JVisualVM, JMC also makes possible to extend its features with additional plugins